# View a graph of pageviews over time for a particular URL from Google Analytics data

Tags: google-analytics, google-data-studio

[image]

There used to be a motion chart in GA to show page view by all URLs. But that’s not working anymore.

Is there a way to pull up all pageview by each URL, consolidate it into a single graph over time?   Maybe something using data studio or a dashboard?

Answer (score 2):

The motion charts in GA still work. To view them, install and enable Flash player for `https://analytics.google.com`.

In Data Studio, (assuming you have GA added as a data source) add a time series chart with Dimension set to Date, Month (or another time dimension that is offered within the dimension drop down options), then add Pageviews as the Metric and set the default date range as desired.